# Variable cell referencing within a loop

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have an Office 365 Excel workbook in a shared OneDrive to manage task allocations. Rather than use Mail Merge in Word in conjunction with Excel to send the task emails to the workers, I would like to do this entirely in Excel.

**Context**

The task is to get a bunch of widgets tested and rated. A specific widget (identified by `widget_id`) is always assigned to exactly 2 testers. Each tester can be assigned any number of widgets. Each tester provides a rating for each assigned widget.

**Workbook setup**

In my workbook, I have a sheet `testers` with 2 columns depicting a list of testers and a third boolean column as email sent flag.

- A tester email
- B tester name
- C email has been sent or not to this tester
- D automatically compiled list of widgets allocated to this tester

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email | name | emailed | allocated |
| `jack@company.com` | Jack | 0 | 990235, 990236, 990231 |
| `mack@company.com` | Mack | 0 | 990235, 990236, 990197, 990003 |
| `iris@company.com` | Iris B | 0 | 990231, 990197, 990003 |

A second sheet `allocations` has information on which widget has been assigned to which testers:

- A widget ID
- B email of tester 1 assigned to the widget (data validation from column A of `testers` sheet)
- E email of tester 2 assigned to the widget (data validation from column A of `testers` sheet)
- columns C-D and F-J are not relevant for the current issue.

As shown in the example below, widget 990235 has been assigned to Jack and Mack.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| widget_id | email1 | email1thanked | rating1 | email2 | email2thanked | rating2 | actionsent | difference | average |
| 990235 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990236 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990231 | `jack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990197 | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |
| 990003 | `mack@company.com` | 0 |  | `iris@company.com` | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |

A third sheet `text` contains email texts:
(Only the first email, i.e. row 2 is relevant for the question - the other rows are to demonstrate that the sheet has other email texts for other purposes too)

- A name of email (so that we can refer to each text by name  -not to be sent)
- B description- of email (so that we know the purpose of the email - not to be sent)
- C subject of email
- D body of email
- E the email signature text

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | description | subject | body | signoff |
| allocated | initial email informing testers which widgets have been allocated to them | List of your widgets | `<p>Thank you for agreeing to test the widgets.</p><p>The IDs of the widgets assigned to you are as following:</p>` | `<p>Best regards,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>The Batman</p>` |
| thanks | thank you email after each rating submission by tester | Thank you for submitting your rating | `<p>Thank you for submitting your rating. </p><p>I'll get back to you with further actions once I have heard from the other tester.</p>` | `<p> Best regards,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Robin</p>` |
| average | the email sent to the 2 testers of a widget when their rating difference is low | All done! | `<p>Great stuff! You and the other tester were really close, so I'll just average your ratings. </p><p>Nothing more to do. </p>` | `<p>Cheerio,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Superman</p>` |
| discuss | the email sent to the 2 testers of a widget when their rating difference is moderate | Can you talk? | `<p>You and the other tester are a bit apart. </p><p>Can you please have a discussion and see if you can come to an agreement? </p>` | `<p>Bye now,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Wonderwoman</p>` |
| third | the email sent to the 2 testers of a widget when their rating difference is large | Gonna escalate this | `<p>Uh, oh! You and the other tester are quite some way from each other.</p><p> I'll have to refer this to a third tester. </p>` | `<p>Toodloo,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Catwoman</p>` |
| reminder | the email sent to the testers whose ratings have not been received by reminder dates | C'mon now | `<p>Seems you are busy.</p><p> The IDs of the widgets for which ratings are awaited from you are as following:</p>` | `<p>Kind regards,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Aquaman</p>` |

**What I want to happen**

I want to have a single link (or button) labeled "Send emails" somewhere (e.g. in cell D1) on `testers` sheet.

When I click this link/button:

Excel should do a *mail merge*:
All testers (listed on `testers` sheet) *who have been allocated at least one widget* on the `allocations` sheet (i.e. appears at least once in either column B or column E) AND who have not been already emailed about it (`testers` sheet column C `emailed` value 0) should be sent an email.
After sending the email to a tester, Excel should set the column C flag (`emailed`) to 1 for that tester.

The email "to" field would be the tester's email.

The email to be sent is the email named `allocated` on the `text` sheet.

The subject would be as per `subject` column.

The way to assemble the email body is:
`<p>`
+ "Dear "
+ `tester name`
+ ","
+ `</p>`
+ `body`
+ `<p>`
+ list of widget IDs from `allocations` sheet for which the tester email is listed as `email1` or `email2` (comma separated))
+ `</p>`
+ `signoff`

Sample email:

To: `jack@company.com`
Subject: List of your widgets
Body:

```
<p>Dear Jack,</p>
<p>Thank you for agreeing to test the widgets.</p><p>The IDs of the widgets assigned to you are as following:</p>
<p>990235, 990236, 990231</p>
<p>Best regards,</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>The Batman</p>
```

**What I need**

My key challenges with the loop:
How do I loop through the list of testers to send these emails

1. I don't know upfront how many testers there will be, so I reckon I'll need to use the `do until` loop (as opposed to `for` loop), telling VBA to keep going through the rows till it hits an empty cell. But unsure how to do that.
2. I am unsure how, within the loop I can refer to a cell address dynamically ... I understand `Range("A2")`, but instead of "2" if I need to use a variable/counter within the loop, how might I do that?

**What I have**

I reckon I could assemble the email for a single recipient as following:

```
Public Sub SendAllocationEmail()

Dim AllocationCount As Integer
Dim FocalTester As String
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim NewEmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set NewEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set AllocationsSheetRange1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("allocations").Range("B2:B1000")
Set AllocationsSheetRange2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("allocations").Range("E2:E1000")
Set EmailSheetRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("text").Range("A2:E6")
Set TestersRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("testers").Range("A2:D1000")

FocalTester = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("testers").Range("B2")
AllocationCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.countif(AllocationsSheetRange1,FocalTester) + Application.WorksheetFunction.countif(AllocationsSheetRange2,FocalTester)

If AllocationCount > 0 Then

  NewEmailItem.To = FocalTester

  NewEmailItem.Subject = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup("allocated", EmailSheetRange, 3, False)

  NewEmailItem.HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & 
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("testers").Range("B2") & ",</p>" & _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup("allocated", EmailSheetRange, 4, False) & _
  "<p>" & Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(FocalTester, TestersRange, 4, False) & 
  "</p>" & 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup("allocated", EmailSheetRange, 5, False)

  NewEmailItem.Send

End If

End Sub
```